# Paid for Apps with Intel XDK

Tags: html, intel-xdk

I'm evaluating Intel XDK as a possible solution for developing cross platform mobile apps. I can see from the documentation that you can do in app ads and in app purchases in XDK via Cordova plugins, however there is no mention of whether the apps themselves can be offered on the various app stores as paid for apps or whether they need to be free.

Its not clear from the build and deploy documentation how to build a paid app. I would expect that either XDK or the app store would require pricing information. However for example, the docs show how to generate an app certificate for the Apple app store, but these instructions don't seem to mention pricing either.

I'm guessing from what i've read so far that only free apps are possible and then you need to make money from within the app. Can anyone tell me what the answer is. The free model does not suit the particular app I'm investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Intel XDK will just build the apps for you, you can sell it in App Stores or make it free, its up to you. You have to set the price while submitting the apps to the various App stores on the apple or google website, not in XDK.

Answer (score 0):

As the developer of the application, it's your decision in regards to defining your app as Free or Paid with a particular price per country location. The app stores have a dashboard/portal for configuring this attribute of your application. (Android-[Google Play Developer Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html); iOS - [iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH1-SW1); Windows Phone - [Windows Phone Dev Center](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2012/09/26/how-i-price-my-windows-phone-apps/))